# What is the time complexity of an algorithm that loops over a list of strings and then also loops over each character of each string?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I just did an interview where my solution involved this algorithm, but I could not say with confidence what the time complexity was.

Psuedocode example:

```
arr = ["hello", "this", "is", "some", "different", "length", "strings"]

function (arr)
    for string in arr
        for char in string
            // do stuff in constant time
```

I initially thought that the complexity as O(N * M) where N is the length of the array and M is the length of each string, but if the strings vary in length I cannot characterize all their lengths with a constant M.

EDIT: strings in the array don't have to be real words and can be any string of arbitrary length

Comment: It's linear, so O(n) (it'a been 30 years, since I've done that, so not an answer)

Comment: I assume that the average length of the words won't change, since they're real words.  So then the only changing quantity is the length of the array.  So, as @Max says, the complexity is O(N).

Comment: @CryptoFool I used real words here as an example but let's assume these can be any string of arbitrary length

Comment: The total number of operations done is the sum of the numbers of characters in each string.  You could express that another way, as the number of strings multiplied by the average number of characters per string.

Comment: I see you now say your lists contain arbitrary strings.  Do those strings tend to grow in size as the list's size increases? How would you expect the average string size to change when you have 1 million strings vs 100K strings?

Comment: @CryptoFool So you could say the time complexity is O(M) for each string in the array, where M is the average number of characters in each string, and O(N) for the whole algorithm where N is the length of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, where the amount of work you do doesn't depend solely on the number of elements in the input array but also on a property of those elements (namely, their length), you're correct that simply describing the algorithm as linear or O(n) would be inadequate.

If all the strings are indeed of arbitrary length, you could technically describe the time-complexity as being 'pseudo-polynomial' or 'pseudo-linear'. Although the lengths of the strings are arbitrary (as you put it, you can't give a fixed value to 'm'), you could still describe the complexity as O(nm) where `m` is the length of the largest string in the input (It's not important that `m` is unknown or arbitrary: you could say the same thing about `n`). It would also be correct to say the algorithm is in O(nm) or even Θ(nm) for `m` as the average length of the input strings. These are just specific ways of saying that it is pseudo-linear.

But if you make more qualifying assumptions or re-frame what you interpret as the 'input' of the algorithm, then you *could* describe it as linear. For example, if you can bound the maximum length of any string in the input by any constant (eg if you know there will be no string longer than 10,000 characters), then saying the algorithm is O(n) would be completely correct. You could also say that the algorithm is linear in the total number of characters in the input (rather than in the number of words), or linear in the average input string length.